# How to make Kivy, opencv and tensorflow work together

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, opencv, kivy

Hi I am trying to make kivy, opencv and tensorflow work together, however it is reall slow, so that my model can't predict anything, because the image isn't updated frequently enough. I believe it is because something between kivy and opencv isn't working right, because with only opencv it works completly fine. But I need it as an app so not using kivy isn't an option.

If anyone could look over the code or has any ideas whatsoever on how to fix this problem, I'd appreciate it.

Here's the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import mediapipe as mp
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
import tensorflow

class CamApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic  # Holistic model
        self.mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils  # Drawing utilities

        self.sequence = []
        # Tensorflow keras library, cause keras couldn't import
        self.keras = tensorflow.keras.utils
        self.sequential = tensorflow.keras.models
        self.tensorboard = tensorflow.keras.callbacks
        self.layers = tensorflow.keras.layers

        # def. results and model as True as long as they haven't been initialized
        self.results = None
        self.model = None
        # Actions that we try to detect
        self.actions = np.array(['hello', 'iloveyou', 'thanks'])
        # Path for the training data
        self.DATA_PATH = os.path.join('MP_Data')
        # Videos are going to be 30 frames in length
        self.sequence_length = 30
        # colors for displaying
        self.colors = [(245, 117, 16), (117, 245, 16), (16, 117, 245)]
        self.img1=Image()
        layout = BoxLayout()
        layout.add_widget(self.img1)
        #opencv2 stuffs
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/33.0)
        return layout

    def update(self, dt):


        self.preprocessData()
        # detection variables

        sentence = []
        predictions = []
        threshold = 0.5

        # Set mediapipe model -> landmarks for pose, face and hands to detect the gestures
        with self.mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
            if self.cap.isOpened():

                # Read feed
                ret, frame = self.cap.read()
                # Make detections
                image, results = self.mediapipe_detection(frame, holistic)
                # Draw landmarks
                self.draw_styled_landmarks(image, results)  # draw the landmarks

                # Prediction logic
                keypoints = self.extract_keypoints(results)  # extract the key points from the landmarks
                self.sequence.append(keypoints)
                self.sequence = self.sequence[-30:]

                if len(self.sequence) == 30:
                    res = self.model.predict(np.expand_dims(self.sequence, axis=0))[
                        0]  # np.expand_dims -> capsule our sequence array so we have the right shape (1, 30 , 1662) instead of (30, 1662)
                    predictions.append(np.argmax(
                        res))  # graps the highest value out of res and predicts this for example if index 1 is the highest than it appends Iloveyou to predictions

                    # Viz logic -> np.unique... checks that the last 10 predictions were the same as the act. prediction
                    if np.unique(predictions[-10:])[0] == np.argmax(res):
                        if res[np.argmax(res)] > threshold:  # only when the prediction is greater than 50% sure
                            # displaying the word only if the word before was another word
                            if len(sentence) > 0:
                                if self.actions[np.argmax(res)] != sentence[-1]:
                                    sentence.append(self.actions[np.argmax(res)])
                            else:
                                sentence.append(self.actions[np.argmax(res)])
                    # just displaying the last 5 given words
                    if len(sentence) > 5:
                        sentence = sentence[-5:]

                    # Viz probabilities
                    image = self.prob_viz(res, self.actions, image)

                # displaying the sentence at the top
                cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (640, 40), (245, 117, 16), -1)
                cv2.putText(image, ' '.join(sentence), (3, 30),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        # convert it to texture
        buf1 = cv2.flip(image, 0)
        buf = buf1.tostring()
        texture1 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        #if working on RASPBERRY PI, use colorfmt='rgba' here instead, but stick with "bgr" in blit_buffer.
        texture1.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        # display image from the texture
        self.img1.texture = texture1

    def train(self, X_train=0, y_train=0):
        # creating a directory for the Logs
        log_dir = os.path.join('Logs')
        # just needed while training
        tb_callback = self.tensorboard.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)
        # initializing the model as a Sequential with six neuron layers of whom 3 are LSTM and 3 are DENSE Layers
        self.model = self.sequential.Sequential()
        self.model.add(self.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=(30, 1662)))
        self.model.add(self.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(self.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(self.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(self.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(self.layers.Dense(self.actions.shape[0], activation='softmax'))

        # compiling the model -> Adam stands for ADAptive Moment estimation meaning it decides whether we want past changes to affect the new changes we made or not -> to minimize the loss function (get as close as possible to the 100% accurancy)
        self.model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

        # Just needed while training
        #self.model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=170, callbacks=[tb_callback])
        #self.model.save("action4.h5")

    def preprocessData(self):
        self.train()
        self.model.load_weights('action4.h5')

    def prob_viz(self, res, actions, input_frame):
        # vizualizing the percentage how much the given frame matches with one of the trained sequences
        output_frame = input_frame.copy()
        for num, prob in enumerate(res): # num = 0 or 1 or2 and prob the probabilities
            cv2.rectangle(output_frame, (0, 60 + num * 40), (int(prob * 100), 90 + num * 40), self.colors[num], -1)
            cv2.putText(output_frame, actions[num], (0, 85 + num * 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2,
                        cv2.LINE_AA)

        return output_frame
    # Set mediapipe model
    # get the key points so that the model can use them for training and realtime analysation
    def extract_keypoints(self, results):
        pose = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z, res.visibility] for res in results.pose_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.pose_landmarks else np.zeros(33*4)
        face = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.face_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.face_landmarks else np.zeros(468*3)
        lh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.left_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(21*3)
        rh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.right_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(21*3)
        return np.concatenate([pose, face, lh, rh])

    def mediapipe_detection(self, image, model):
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # COLOR CONVERSION BGR 2 RGB
        image.flags.writeable = False                  # Image is no longer writeable
        self.results = model.process(image)                 # Process the image with mediapipe holistics to get the landmarks
        image.flags.writeable = True                   # Image is now writeable
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  # COLOR CONVERSION RGB 2 BGR
        return image, self.results

    #  Displaying the detected connections on the image
    def draw_styled_landmarks(self, image, results):
        # Draw face connections
        self.mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.face_landmarks, self.mp_holistic.FACEMESH_TESSELATION,
                                 self.mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,110,10), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
                                 self.mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,256,121), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
                                 )
        # Draw pose connections
        self.mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, self.mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                 self.mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,22,10), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 self.mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,44,121), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )
        # Draw left hand connections
        self.mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.left_hand_landmarks, self.mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                                 self.mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,22,76), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 self.mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,44,250), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )
        # Draw right hand connections
        self.mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.right_hand_landmarks, self.mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                                 self.mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 self.mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried it with only opencv and it worked completly fine so I don't know where the problem occurs that, but it just updates really slowly until it hangs it self and doesn't respond anymore.
Android studio and chaquopy aren't an option, cause mediapipe isn't supported there, so it has to be kivy to create an android app..

Comment: That's a lot of code, and mostly unreproducible (you don't provide the `.h5` file, for example). Just an observation:  Why are you redefining the model architecture *every time* the app updates?

Comment: And a general tip - **time** your code/functions to locate the bottleneck. If you are debugging via USB you can `print` to the Logcat directly from the app.

Comment: @stateMachine uhmm I read once that that is necessary but if it ain't I'll stop doing it

Comment: @stateMachine also I somehow can't load the .h5 file up that's why you can't see it.. and thanks for the tip with the timing

Answer (score 0):

I have idea that is you can use multi threading for your app. Split parts of your app and run separate process for each parts. Of course you should consider semaphore. Also, you can optimize your model loading, Consider loading the model once during the initialization `(__init__)` rather than in the `preprocessData` method, which is called in every frame.

At the end, I suggest Using Python profiling tools (`cProfile`, `timeit`) to identify bottlenecks and areas that need optimization.

Comment: Do you have a tip or idea which parts would best be splitted in process, cause I have the feeling that they mostly have to run one after one...

Comment: Sure, You can move your `model loading phase` in another thread, also, you can move your `data preprocessing` , `camera frame processing` and `drawing logic` into separate threads.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).